# Using Func<,> and Action extensions for sql query

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to create a generic SqlDataReader extension that can be used for every class, without creating the Command, ... every time, again and again.

This is what I got so far

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Reader<TResult>(
    this SqlConnection d2Connection,
    string Query, Action<SqlParameterCollection> parameters,
    CommandType CommandType = CommandType.Text)
```

And this is working so far, but with this approach I can't really set Class properties.

What I would like is something like the following

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Reader<TResult>(
        this SqlConnection d2Connection,
        string Query, Action<SqlParameterCollection> parameters,
        Func<string, string> output,
        CommandType CommandType = CommandType.Text)
```

So that I can call it like this (example)

```
using (var Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    var dom = Conn.Reader<User>( "SELECT ID, NAME, FIRSTNAME FROM TABLE WHERE UserID=@UserID",
    p =>
    {
        p.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
    },
    s =>
    {
        s.NAME = [Something Here];
        s.FIRSTNAME = [Something Here]
    }
    ).ToList();
}
```

But so far, I couldn't get it to work and I'm wondering if someone could help me.

Thanks in advance

### EDIT

thanks to the answer of Jakub Lortz

```
using (var Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    var dom = Conn.Reader<User>( "SELECT ID, NAME, FIRSTNAME FROM TABLE WHERE UserID=@UserID",
    p =>
    {
        p.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
    },
    dr =>
    {
        return new User()
        {
            NAME = dr["NAME"].ToString(),
            FIRSTNAME = dr["FIRSTNAME"].ToString()
        };
    }
    ).ToList();
}
```

The syntax of the function call seems allright, now I need the implementation.
Got this so far (Single) but I would need it for a list.

```
public static TResult Reader2<TResult>(
    this SqlConnection d2Connection,
    string Query, Action<SqlParameterCollection> parameters,
    Func<SqlDataReader, TResult> Result,
    CommandType CommandType = CommandType.Text)
{
    TResult result;
    using (SqlCommand d2Command = new SqlCommand(Query, d2Connection))
    {
        d2Command.CommandType = CommandType;

        if (parameters != null)
            parameters(d2Command.Parameters);

        if (d2Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            d2Connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader d2Reader = d2Command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            result = Result(d2Reader);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use something like Dapper?  It already does this for you and it's incredibly efficient.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to re-invent [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), it actually is the ORM used to power this site.

Comment: Part of self education.
To see if it's pracical in other circumstances as well. Not always relying on third party projects

Comment: By setting class properties you mean support for mapping db columns to properties with different names? Cannot this mapping be done by using attributes on the User properties?

Comment: Without the Func<,> it is working, using .NET reflection. But I prefer working with internal / protected properties, and there are some dificulties with Reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to use the `output` function to map the results of the command to TResult. So the type shouldn't be `Func<string, string>`, but `Func<SqlDataReader, TResult>`.

Now you can use

```
using (var Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    var dom = Conn.Reader<User>( "SELECT ID, NAME, FIRSTNAME FROM TABLE WHERE UserID=@UserID",
    p =>
    {
        p.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
    },
    dr =>
    {
        return new User()
        {
            NAME = dr["NAME"].ToString(),
            FIRSTNAME = dr["FIRSTNAME"].ToString()
        };
    }
    ).ToList();
}
```

In the `Reader` method, iterate through the datareader and call `output` in each iteration:

```
var result = new List<TResult>();
while (reader.Read()) result.Add(output(reader));
```

Comment: in first glace, this looks exactly what I needed with 1 minor change NAME = dr["NAME"]; => NAME = dr["NAME"].ToString(), (note the comma iso the semicolon). But aside that, Thanks!!

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but how, just the Func<,> part, can this be turned into the output of IEnumerable<TResult>?

Comment: @DieterB Added to the answer.